# dired-mode: M-! does not recognize aliases from .bashrc

Tags: shell, emacs, dired

I have an alias `alias lpr2='lpr -o sides=one-sided -o number-up=2'` defined in `.bashrc` for easy printing. I can use it in the (emacs) shell, but when I use `M-!` on a pdf file in `dired-mode` and type in `lpr2`, I receive `/bin/bash: lpr2: command not found`. How can aliases be made available in `dired-mode` on `M-!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use aliases in <kbd>M-!</kbd>. However, you can define the variable `lpr-switches` so you can use all the Emacs' printing commands with requested behaviour.

Comment: As far as I can see, `lpr-switches` only allows for one set of parameters. I have aliases with quite different sets of parameters. Also, aliases not related to printing. Is then a solution to turn them into shell scripts in `/usr/local/bin` or so?

Comment: @MariusHofert: Definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you can explicitly invoke `bash` in its interactive mode, which reads `~/.bashrc` and makes aliases available.  Use this as your shell command:

```
bash -ic 'lpr2 "$@"' -- *
```

You'll get some harmless warnings (at least I do), but it will work.

I assume you probably meant `!` (`dired-do-shell-command`) rather than `M-!` (`shell-command`), which is not related to dired mode.